# JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory Android Studio (Flutter)

Tags: java, android, flutter, android-studio, dart

I am using OSX Yosemite on my old mac. When I installed emulator and try to create a run a Flutter project, I started getting an error about JDK 17. I deleted JDK 17 and installed JDK and also set my path in bash profile to "Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-1.8.0_321.jdk/Contents/Home". However, my Android studio is still giving this error.

```
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.

Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I spent hours solving this. Please help me. Thank you very much.

Comment: What is the value of environment variable JAVA_HOME ? See, for example_ https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-set-java_home-environment-variable-on-mac-os-x/

Comment: Try:
export JAVA_HOME=~/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/YOUR_REQUIRED_JAVA/Contents/Home

Comment: It is JAVA_HOME and on terminal it returns correct path but on Android Studio, it gives an error. @3squad, I am doing same.

Comment: Have you run `source ~/.zshenv`? If yes and you still get the error try to restart the computer, it's probably using the previous JAVA_HOME in the PATH.

Answer (score 36):

For **Windows**:

The problem is because of trace of old Android Studio java folder, just delete this folder and it starts working:

```
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre
```

The new Android Studio Electric Eel is using `jbr`, not `jre`.

---

For **macOS**:
If you are using macOS replace the path in .bash_profile or .zshrc

```
export JAVA_HOME="/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home"
```

with

```
export JAVA_HOME="/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home"
```

Comment: Windows was a bit more difficult than deleting the folder. I had to open system Environment Variables and change `JAVA_HOME` from `[...]\jre` to `[...]\jbr`. I also had to restart Windows before Android Studio picked up this change. More instructions on the Environment Variables can be found at: https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-set-java_home-on-windows-10/

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is the perfect fix. Use  `nano ~/.bash_profile`  and or  `nano ~/.zshrc` to update the Java Home path

Comment: Thank you very much, I got this error for almost two years with no solution, until now.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue. Problem was due to 2 versions of Android Studio installed on same device. One was in applications folder and other was in Downloads folder. I was using Android Studio in Downloads folder and it's installation files are referring to old JDK plugin that was set for another Android Studio because both have similar paths.

```
/Applications/AndroidStudio.app/Contents/plugins/java/lib/jdkAnnotations.jar
```

After deleting old Android Studio and moving other one into Application folder resolved my issue. Thanks everybody for helping me out.